# Python WatchedFileHandler and RotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging

I tried using RotatingFileHandler and WatchedFileHandler together, but getting duplicate logs. Can anybody help me please.

Code snippet to add the handlers

```html
log_root = getLogger(__name__).logger <br>
log_root.addHandler(RotatingFileHanlder(__name__, maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=10)<br> log_root.addHandler(watchedFileHanlder(__name__)
```

Comment: Please add code sample so we can help you.

Comment: Got fixed. log_root.addHandler(watchedFileHanlder(__name__, 'w') fixed the issue

Comment: I hit the same issue, but as 'w' to WatchedFileHandler doesn't fix the problem, still some entries are duplicated. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

There's no point in adding a `WatchedFileHandler` *and* a `RotatingFileHandler`.

- If you want to control file rotation yourself, use a `RotatingFileHandler`.
- If you want externally controlled log rotation (e.g. using `logrotate`), use a `WatchedFileHandler`.

Also, you might use `__name__` for a logger, but typically a different file name is used for handlers.

Comment: You might like to add the crux of the question, whether the rotating file handler also does the "Watching", which is does.

Answer (score 0):

`RotatingFileHandler` also does the "watching".

Either create one of both and let them log into different files (in your snippet they are both logging to `__name__`), or, if you like to use the rotating principle, then only use the `RotatingFileHandler`.